# Copy lines of txt. files

Tags: command-line-interface

Hey I'm just learning CLI basics and created an exercises for myself. I'm using the standard terminal on macOS. I've tested my code, but I'm not getting the result I hoped for.

1. Exercise: Copy the 3rd line of x amount of text files and paste it into a single file called result.txt

`head -n 3 *.txt | tail -n 1 *.txt > results.txt`

Comment: What you want is a pipeline.  Your `tail` statement should not include a file name -- it reads from the pipe.  `head -n 3 *.txt | tail -n 1 > results.txt`  However, even that isn't right.  The `head` is going to produce a single list of lines from ALL of the files, and the `tail` only returns the last list from the last file.  You're going to need a `for` loop here.

Comment: Please [edit] the post with name of the shell you are using and specify how "both of my answers are wrong"... Actually consider policy of asking one question per post - those two questions looks quite unrelated to me....

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks a lot. I'm not familiar with the `for` loop. I will return to this exercise again at a later stage.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov done. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this:

```
for name in *.txt
do
    head -n 3 $name | tail -n 1
done > results.txt
```

That way, the head/tail combo is done one file at a time, producing a combined result in `results.txt`.  If you need to know which file it is, you can add a marker:

```
for name in *.txt
do
    echo ======== $name ========
    head -3 $name | tail -1
done > results.txt
```